# what does the following code means?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, execute

> I met this question in a interview occassion, the man asked me what is the result if i compile and execute the following code, and why. I am curious about this question and i did not really got it.
>
> When i typing `gcc f1.c f2.c` and then `./a.out`, it outputs a weird number:`1717986918` in my x64 PC, and then i add a line in f2.c: extern double get_val(); it outputs 5.

f1.c：

```
double get_val()
{
    return 5.6;
}
```

f2.c：

```
#include<stdio.h>
//extern double get_val();
int main()
{
    int a=get_val();
    printf("%d\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What answer did you expect?   Also, prior to an "edit" the "extern" was uncommented... did that version give you the output you expected???  Lastly, with "extern" commented out, I get a warning message from "gcc", do you get one ???

Comment: Lot's of good resources on C, methods, functions and variable declarations on YouTube as well. Hang in there, and good luck with the job hunt!

Comment: @BasicIsaac: Avoid resources that refer to "methods"; C doesn't have them. (C++ member functions are sometimes called "methods", but that's not strictly correct either.)

Comment: @KeithThompson thanks for the heads up. I clicked on the C# tag and somehow ended up here. I don't see how this question how so many downvotes, it really is weird that the function would return a large number without the get_val() reference.

Comment: @BasicIsaac: Not that weird; see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In `f2.c`, prior to the change, there is no declaration for `get_val`.  So it assumes by default that the function returns an `int`.  Because this does not match the actual return type of the function, this results in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

When you add a declaration, the correct return type of the function is known so the code works as expected.

Comment: The assumption that an undeclared functions returns `int` applies only prior to the 1999 ISO C standard (C99), which dropped the "implicit `int`" rule. In C99 or later, a call an undeclared function is a constraint violation, requiring a compile-time diagnostic. Once the diagnostic is issued, if it's non-fatal, the subsequent behavior of the program is undefined, but the compiler can reject it altogether.

Comment: @KeithThompson nevertheless, common behaviour of compilers (even in C99 mode) is to issue a diagnostic and then proceed using the C89 behaviour

Comment: @M.M: Unfortunately true.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to see how do you get the 1717986918 result and I can't figure out. In the two ways you decribe, I got a 5 printed. That's why:

- You're "parsing" the double value of your function return whitin a int type (but

  ```
  int a = get_val();
  ```
- After that, you are printing it on a format for a decimal

  ```
  printf("%d\n", a);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the `get_val()` function with no visible declaration.

Don't do that.  As of C99, the language forbids (see below) any call to a function without a visible declaration. (That declaration *should* be a prototype, which specifies the types of the parameters, but that's not required.)

Prior to C99 (which dropped the "implicit `int`" rule), a call to an undeclared function would require the compiler to *assume* that the function returns a result of type `int`, and that it expects the number and types of arguments that the call actually passes. If that assumption is violated by the actual function definition, as it is here since `get_val()` returns a `double` result, the behavior is undefined.

(By "forbids", I mean that such a call is a *constraint violation*. That means a conforming compiler must diagnose it, but is not required to reject it. Many compilers still permit calls to undeclared functions, often with a non-fatal warning, and implement the pre-C99 semantics. So a compiler might let you get away with it.  Don't.)

So what happens is that `get_val()` is called, it returns a `double` result with the value `5.6` -- but the caller is expecting an `int` result, so it stores some undefined garbage value in `a`.

The value you're seeing, `1717986918`, happens to be `0x66666666` in hexadecimal.  In IEEE floating-point, at least on my system, the value `5.6` is represented as `0x6666666666661640`.  Apparently the value being stored happens to be the first half of the `double` value (most likely `double` is 8 bytes and `int` is 4 bytes).

So that explains the behavior you're seeing, but you should *not* count on it.

Never call a function without a visible declaration.

The usual way to get a visible declaration for a function defined in another source file is to `#include` the right header.

Here's an example of the right way to do it:

`f1.h`:

```
#ifndef F1_H
#define F1_H

extern double get_val(void);

#endif
```

`f1.c`:

```
#include "f1.h"

double get_val(void)
{
    return 5.6;
}
```

`f2.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "f1.h"

int main(void) {
    int a = get_val();
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I've changed `()` to `(void)` in all the function declarations and definitions. This specifies that the function takes no arguments, rather than an unspecified number of arguments. The difference is that with `double get_val()`, the compiler (probably) won't complain if you call it incorrectly, for example `get_val("foo")`.